# ngOnInit() runs methos parallel?

Tags: angular, ngoninit

In my Angular project I call the method `ConnectToHueBridge()` and `listAllGoups()` from `ngOnInit()`. It seems to me that both methods will be parallel executed. But I need to run first `ConnectToHueBridge()` and then `listAllGoups()`. How can I do that?

```
var MyHue = new huepi();

@Component({

selector: 'my-app',
template: `
<h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>
<div>
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let group of lightgroups">
      {{group}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<Button (click)="listAllGroups()"> Get Groups</Button>`,
 })

export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  lightgroups: string[] = [];

constructor(){
}

ngOnInit(){
  this.ConnectToHueBridge(MyHue);
  this.listAllGroups();
}

listAllGroups(){
  for(var g in MyHue.Groups){
    this.lightgroups.push(g);
  }
  console.log("done loading groups");
}

 ConnectToHueBridge(MyHue:any){
 //do some stuff
 }
}
}
```

If I click on the button to execute the method everything works fine.
How can I execute the methods after each other?

Answer (score 1):

You have to make them observable.

```
ConnectToHueBridge(MyHue:any): Observable<any> {
    //do some stuff
    return Observable.of(true);
}
```

Then, in your `ngOnInit` do this

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.ConnectToHueBridge('xxx').subscribe(data => {
        // data = true, you can change it in your function
        this.listAllGroups();
    });
}
```

Comment: this did not work for me, still the same problem. I have some console.log() in the `ConnectToHueBridge()` method and a console.log() in `listAllGroups()` method but the output in the browser console is mixed. There should be first all logs from `connectToHueBridge()` and then all from `listAllGroups()` so I know the data is ready to show it in the HTML. If I hit the button to execute the `listAllGroups()` again the data will be shown in HTML.

Comment: Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: I figured out, that the `MyHue` object is not ready when the `listAllGroups()` is executed, so it skips the for loop and only displays the console.log()
After the HTML is displayed and I hit the button to execute `listAllGroups()` again, the for loop runs and the content will be shown in the HTML
Do you have any other ideas to solve this?

Comment: Sorry for the answer delay, mother's day in my country. Well it seems obvious : if your problem is the MyHue object, shouldn't you check if you have a valid object ?

Comment: Thank you for further help. Well  I edited this part:
    `listAllGroups(){
      console.log(MyHue.Groups);
      for(var g in MyHue.Groups){ //MyHue.Groups returns a array
        console.log(g);
        this.lightgroups.push(g);
      }
      console.log("done loading groups");
    }`

the first time console.log(MyHue.Groups) returns a empty array. If I execute it again manually it provides the elements I need.

The MyHue Object is declared with a instance of a other JS lib like this:
     `var MyHue:any = new huepi();`